# How to make both the markers and their tooltips visible using the leaflet package in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, tooltip

I am using the `leaflet` package in `RStudio` to plot a data set containing geographical co-ordinates on a map.

My code stands as follows:

```
setwd("E:/RTests")
library(leaflet)
library(maps)
mydata <- read.csv("data1.csv", check.names=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

mydata <- data.frame(mydata)
leaflet(data = mydata) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers (~lon, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(emp), label = ~as.character(emp))
```

The output is fine. However, I now want the tooltips associated to the markers to be permanently visible. As is, the tooltips appear only when I hover the mouse on the markers.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it!

```
leaflet(data = mydata) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers (~lon, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(emp), label = ~as.character(emp), labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T))
```